# Big Confidence Interval for seemingly rather accurate variable, NonLinearModelFit

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, parameters

I used `NonLinearModelFit` to fit a function of the form `a*Abs(Cos(x))^b` to a set of 5 points, that each have a uncertainty. My coding is:

```
p1 = {0, 119/720}
p2 = {30/180 Pi, 3/25}
p3 = {-30/180 Pi, 1/10}
p4 = {60/180 Pi, 1/40}
p5 = {-60/180 Pi, 7/200}
p = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}
errors = {1/Sqrt[595],1/(6 Sqrt[2]),1/(2 Sqrt[15]),1/Sqrt[15],1/Sqrt[21]}
nnn = NonlinearModelFit[p, {a (Abs[Cos[x]])^b}, {a, b}, x, 
  Weights -> 1/errors^2]
```

`p` is my list of points, and `errors` is the list of uncertainties for each of them.

[image]

I just don't understand why when I use:

```
nnn["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

It gives me a confidence interval for `b`, which is `2.67` of `{-4.92, 10.27}`. If I use a starting point that is even near those values like `b < -3`, I get a fit that looks pretty far off to be a good fit.

```
nnn = NonlinearModelFit[p, {a (Abs[Cos[x]])^b, b < -3}, {a, b}, 
  x, Weights -> 1/errors^2]
```

[image]

So can anybody tell me, why the confidence interval for `b` is so big, because I would expect it to be way smaller?!

Comment: Because you only have 5 data points, would you include those in your question?  (Along with `errors`).  Also, why are `c` and `d` in the list of parameters?

Comment: I added the data points and the errors. c and d were relicts of an old try for the Fit so i removed them now. Thank you! I hope this helps!

Comment: Now that you've removed `c` and `d` from the parameter list, the error degrees of freedom goes from 1 to 3 and the confidence intervals are then much smaller.  (But you can't expect a whole lot from 5 points used to estimate 3 parameters (`a`,`b`, and the error variance.)  I would not be surprised if this question is closed because of having extraneous parameters eating up degrees of freedom.  Here are the confidence bands for the fitted curve:  `Plot[{nnn[x], nnn["MeanPredictionBands"]}, {x, -1.1, 1.1}]`.

Comment: But even if I add c and d like this:

`nnn = NonlinearModelFit[p, {a (Abs[Cos[x + d]])^b + c}, {a, b, c, d}, 
  x, Weights -> 1/errors^2]`
the confidence Intervall for b is still as big as it was without c and b?! I don't expect a perfect fit, but i don't understand why the confidence Intervall is so big

Comment: With `c` and `d` in the model you have 5 data points and 5 parameters to be estimated (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and the error variance).  The error variance now has just one degree of freedom.  The associated Student's t-value for a 95% confidence interval is 12.7062.  If you had 100 data points with the model with `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, then the Student's t-value would be 1.985 and the confidence interval would only be about 1/6th the size as having 5 data points.

Comment: So the confidence Interval does not tell me, that b could lie anywhere between  {-4.92, 10,27}? (See confidence Intervall in original question)

Comment: In the updated code the confidence interval for `b` is now `{1.57439, 3.77094}`. Does that not seem reasonable? (Site tip: Use "@user", like @JimB, to make sure the person receives a notification of your reply.) -- And yes, the confidence interval is likely (95%) to contain the true value of the parameter (if all the assumptions about the distribution and sampling are met). The large interval `{-4.92, 10.27}` reflects a large uncertainty due to the small amount of data as Jim explained; it does not mean any value in the interval such as `b = -3` is likely to give a good fit.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : "...And yes, the confidence interval is likely (95%) to contain the true value of the parameter ...". Careful, Icarus...

Comment: @ciao I don't get it. Isn't that the meaning of a CI? Or do you want the 95% spelled out? (Or is it that the assumptions about sampling are probably not met, judging from the data?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 - *A* confidence interval either does, or does not, contain the true parameter. 1 or 0 probability. The "confidence" applies to the method used to generate the intervals. Punctilious, perhaps, but important.

Comment: @ciao Yes quite. But of all possible samples, 95% of the CIs will contain the true value of the parameter.  As a random event, the probability is 95% that a CI will contain the parameter, even though each one either does or does not contain it. (But the data does not have the appearance of a random event, so I don't know what the confidence level would mean in that case. It may merely be, as you say, a "method," perhaps a meaningless one.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 If folks understood the correct interpretation of confidence intervals (exactly as ciao stated), they probably would come to the same conclusion about the usefulness as you just stated.  Mainstream "Frequentist" statistical procedures are judged (by Frequentists) on long term properties and not at all with any one particular sample.  The term "confidence" was used because it wasn't a long-term probability.  Bayesians don't have that restriction.  But I digress...

Comment: In short, `NonlinearModelFit` is working fine.  Your expectations about the size of confidence intervals with small sample sizes compared to the number of estimated parameters needs modification.  To quote Scotty:  "Cap'n! You can't change the laws of physics!" (or the laws of statistics).

Comment: @MichaelE2 My question is answered now, thanks. The problem was i removed c and d here in the question but not in my coding, where I evaluated the confidence Intervall. Turns out that if one keeps c and d in the parameter list but doesnt put them in the function of the fit they are set to 1 and the confidence Intervall for b is huge. If you remove c and d as shown in the question the problem does not occur.  I should delete this question because as it is formulate now after editing there is no question to be answered...

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` sets the starting values of all parameters to 1 (unless one explicitly puts in another starting value).  Because your function does not include c and d, there's no information in the data with respect to the model to change c and d so they remain at 1.  This does not affect the prediction.  It only affects the degrees of freedom for error and in this case lowers the degrees of freedom by 2.  If you had a large sample size, this would not cause a problem.  It is only because of the small sample size that there is a practical issue.